# Is there a REST API to get the build errors in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

So, here is what I know:

1. I can get the build data, there I can find the `logs` property with a url.
2. Accessing the logs url returns an array of links to the various parts of the build log (presumably a part per build task in the order of the latter in the build definition)
3. The url in each part gets me the text logged by the respective task.
4. I can parse it and everything matching `##[error]` corresponds to an error logged on the build summary page.

I am curious if this is the best way to do it if I only need to get the build errors. I do not need the whole log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the [Build Timeline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get) and check the results there if there is an errors.

The API response contains the property `issues`, so just check if it's not null and print the issue message.

For example (in PowerShell):

```
# Get here the response from the api
$response = Invoke-RestMethod ......
$errors = $response.records.Where({ $_.issues -ne $null })
$errors.ForEach({
   # Task name
   $_.name
   # Error message
   $_.issues.ForEach({ $_.message })
})
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I need.